# Diagnose Apache Spark job

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-spark

Is there a way to diagnose spark job when loading data from Elasticsearch index. So far I don't know what's going on, except for the executor log

`15/09/18 11:15:50 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 325.4 KB, free 25.9 GB)
15/09/18 11:15:51 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_2_0 not found, computing it
15/09/18 11:15:51 INFO CacheManager: Partition rdd_2_4 not found, computing it`

The ES index is almost 114.4GB with 22,951,540 documents, trying to cache this in memory so I can run some analysis on the dataset

Spark is running in standalone and keeps going forever until it times out with Out of Memory Exception.

## Spark Cluster

`Workers: 4
Cores: 128 Total, 128 Used
Memory: 499.5 GB Total, 200.0 GB Used
Applications: 1 Running, 3 Completed
Drivers: 0 Running, 0 Completed
Status: ALIVE`

Comment: How much memory did you give for your driver and executors?

Comment: @eliasah
spark.driver.memory = "10g"
spark.executor.memory = "50g"

Comment: You are giving 50g of RAM per executor? So 50g per JVM. It turns out, the JVM uses a trick to compress object pointers when heaps are 30.5 GB or less which can lead to wasting memory, reducing CPU performance, and makes the GC struggle with large heaps. You should avoid using above 30.5g of RAM per JVM

Comment: @eliasah, but I have up 499.5G of memory and I thought spark will use that to cache my dataframe in memory?

Comment: from spark UI, Memory: 499.5 GB Total, 200.0 GB Used

Comment: add more executors and lower the executor memory to 30

Comment: hmm, will give that a try - thanks

Comment: So have you tried that? Are you still getting OOME?